# Alert button to dismiss Alert and go back to previous View Controller

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I'm kind of new to Swift and I can't figure this out. I have an Alert that should show on a successful URL request. After a user clicks an `Ok` button on the alert, I need the alert dismissed and I need the presented controller to go back in the navigation stack to the previous view controller. I don't get any errors but nothing happens. If I move the entire code for the Alert inside the CustomClass, then it works fine. I assume I am not referencing the CustomClass the right way. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 struct Alert {
    static func CustomAlert(vc: UIViewController, title: String, message: String){

        var title = "Title...!"
        var message = "Message..."
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (actin) in
            myAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            let vc = CustomClass()
            vc.GoBackToPreviousVC()
        }))
         vc.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
 }

 class: CustomClass: UIViewController {

    func GoBackToPreviousVC(){
        navigationController?popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    function Download(){

      code for URLRequest...

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if (self.response.Status == "200"){
            Alert.CustomAlert(vc: self, title: "", message: "")
        }

      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont create new instance  `let vc = CustomClass()` use the one you passed as parameter

```
struct Alert {
   static func CustomAlert(vc: UIViewController, title: String, message: String){

       var title = "Title...!"
       var message = "Message..."
       let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
       myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (actin) in
           myAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        if let controller = vc as? CustomClass {
           controller.GoBackToPreviousVC()
        }
       }))
        vc.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

And better to use Protocol instead of hard code class

```
protocol Goback {
    func GoBackToPreviousVC()
}


struct Alert {
   static func CustomAlert(vc: UIViewController, title: String, message: String){

       var title = "Title...!"
       var message = "Message..."
       let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
       myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (actin) in
           myAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        if let controller = vc as? Goback {
           controller.GoBackToPreviousVC()
        }
       }))
        vc.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

And confirm your class with that protocol in which you want to use Alert

```
class CustomClass: UIViewController,Goback {

    func GoBackToPreviousVC(){

        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like each time you call your function - you create new View Controller. That why nothing happens. Try to use closure, implement alert function as extension for UIViewController or pass it as function input.Choose what most fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the alert to be inside an extension of `UIViewController` and use `self` to dismiss and `popViewController` in the navigational stack, here is the code:

```swift
extension UIViewController {
    func CustomAlert(title: String, message: String){

        var title = "Title...!"
        var message = "Message..."
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (actin) in
            myAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }))
         present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
 }
```

Usage:

```
class: CustomClass: UIViewController {

    function Download(){

      // code for URLRequest...

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if (self.response.Status == "200") {
            self.CustomAlert(title: "", message: "")
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.3

You add Utility class. I use it like this.

```
public class UtilsClass: NSObject  {
    public static let shared = UtilsClass()

    public func customAlertYN(ViewController:UIViewController,title:String!,actionTitle:String!,message:String!,okButtonString:String!,cancelButtonString:String!,okCallback: @escaping () -> Void = {}){
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let ok = UIAlertAction(title: okButtonString, style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                okCallback()
            })

            let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: cancelButtonString, style: .cancel) { (action) -> Void in

            }

            alert.addAction(ok)
            alert.addAction(cancel)
            ViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
      }
```

And use this way. Add your viewController.

```
UtilsClass.shared.customAlertYN(ViewController: self, title: "Alert", actionTitle: "", message: "Are you sure you want to logout?", okButtonString: "Yes", cancelButtonString: "No",okCallback: {
                //TODO: 
   })
```